# Wie bei Muttern?

Tags: dialect, declension

Der Phrase "wie bei Muttern" ist gängig, obwohl es eigentlich "wie bei Mutter" heißen müsste. Woher kommt sie, entspricht sie in einem Dialekt der gewöhnlichen Deklination? Falls ja, wie wird "Mutter" in diesem Dialekt vollständig dekliniert?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/deklination-von-verwandtschaftsbezeichnungen

Comment: Wie bei Muttern" wird als Redensart gelistet: http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~wie%20bei%20Muttern&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zum Singular Dativ und Akkusativ [**Muttern**](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM08804#XGM08804) (nicht zu verwechseln mit dem Plural der [Schraubenmutter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schraubenmutter)) schreiben die Grimms:

> *Nur der Hausrede des nördlichen Deutschlands gehört die Dat.- und Acc.-Form **Muttern** an, die in demselben Falle gebraucht wird.*

Es handelt sich also um eine Variante aus der norddeutschen Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 5):

Ich vermute dänischen, schwedischen oder norwegischen Einfluss. In diesen Sprachen wird nämlich der bestimmte Artikel -en oder verkürzt -n dem zugehörigen Wort angehängt (z.B. schwedisch "modern" = "die Mutter"), und "bei Muttern" bedeutet ja "bei der Mutter".

Comment: Inhaltlich ist das meiner Ansicht nach eine Ergänzung zur akzeptierten Antwort und wäre vermutlich besser als Kommentar unter jener aufgehoben. Da Ken noch nicht genug Reputation zum Kommentieren hat, könnte vielleicht ein Moderator das ganze konvertieren?

Comment: Inhaltlich ist das meiner Ansicht nach eine eigenständige Antwort, die mit der akzeptierten Antwort nicht im Geringsten in Verbindung steht und daher auch nicht zu einem Kommentar herabgestuft werden sollte.

Answer (score 4):

Vgl. "auf Erden". Es handelt sich dabei um eine alte Form femininer schwacher Deklination.

Comment: Interessant,Danke. Hast Du einen Beleg dafür?

Comment: *Muoter* war immer stark (soweit ich weiß).

Answer (score 2):

Bin mir nicht sicher, wo "bei Muttern" gesagt wird, Süddeutsch ist es jedenfalls nicht. Ich vermute Norddeutsch. Nach Recherche sehe ich, das es im Raum Berlin gebraucht wird: Futtern wie bei Muttern.http://m.maz-online.de/Lokales/Dahme-Spreewald/Futtern-wie-bei-Muttern

Comment: Dafür gibt’s unzählige Treffer im ganzen Land, einschließlich Bayern.

Comment: @chirlu Ich würde den Gebrauch von Muttern und Vattern für die eigenen Eltern auch eher in Norddeutschland verorten. Die Phrase "wie bei Muttern"  könnte sich ausgebreitet haben, weil es so schön griffig ist :)

Comment: Ich kenne das auch nur aus dem Raum Berlin + Brandenburg. In Ba-Wü hatte ich es dagegen noch nie gehört.

Comment: Naja - *Gehört* hab' ich das hier schon, tippe aber trotzdem auf einen "eingewanderten" Gebrauch.

Comment: Meine Reaktion auf *bei Muttern* wäre *aha, a Breiß!* @chirlu.

Comment: "einschließlich Bayer**n**". lol

Answer (score 0):

Ob "Erden" hier Dativ Plural ist? Vgl. Pluralformen wie "die Himmel", "die Wasser".

Comment: Willkommen auf German Language SE! Du hast das jetzt als eigene Antwort gepostet, das ist aber keine Antwort auf die Frage oben, sondern soll vermutlich ein Kommentar zur Antwort von NiceBerlin, oder? Kommentieren ist leider erst mit einer gewissen Reputation freigeschaltet.

Answer (score 0):

Ich spreche einen Tiroler Dialekt, und wir sagen nicht "bei Muttern". Wir sagen aber "bei Seppen" "bei Petern" "bei Fritzen"... wobei das eher ältere Leute tun. Oder eben Leute, die mit einem starken Dialekt aufgewachsen sind. Wie ich beispielsweise.