# "Auf dem Schoß der Frau" - "Auf der Fraus Schoß"?

Tags: phrase, grammaticality, genitive

How does standard High German say

> on the woman's lap

analogously to

> "auf Mutters Schoß"
>
> "auf des Mannes Schoß"

I'm affraid "auf der Frau Schoß" is either obsolete, now, or were not current, ever, and archaic variants I don't know.

**What would be an acceptable way, at least historically, to phrase this other than "auf dem Schoß der Frau"?**

Note:

1. I'm sure this has been asked before, but if posed around an example sentence, like I did, it will be hard to find
2. This question has irked me berfore, but it is also motivated by "Muttern" (e.g. [Futtern wie bei Muttern](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28817/wie-bei-muttern)), which might merit another question for the derivation, if it's not related to this one here, but Grimm notes

   > "nur der hausrede des nördlichen Deutschlands gehört die dat.- und acc.-form muttern an, die in demselben falle gebraucht wird".

   Although it's not clear to me whether "in demselben falle" relates to the preceding example "auf mutters schosz", I read it that way, which does seem to imply "auf Muttern Schoß".
3. This question is also motivated by a possible Fugenlaut *-n* as in [Maschinenverleih](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50005/how-does-the-german-superpower-of-word-chaining-really-work/50012?noredirect=1#comment122175_50012), *Flaschenannahme*, indeed *Fugenlaut*, or, if that's the case "Muttern Schoß".

Comment: I guess that the question reduces to what you wrote in bold type. The rest appears irrelevant. If so, then the answer is "_auf der Frau Schoß_", which is, as you already figured out, obsolete.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich the context of the question would require an answer to show why it became obsolete, or *how* (where, when, whence) it was acceptable. It's there precisely to swart off low effort answers in the likeness of your comment.

Comment: Anyhow, different variants are possible, so it should correctly ask for "the acceptable ways", but not knowing the answer to that, I can't gauge whether that's too broad, so I'll have to leave it as is and hope for the best.

Comment: And if I have to unpack the context for you, one implied part of the question is for the grammaticality of "auf [singular] der Frauen Schoß". I can see that it's a bad question, if there can be multiple different correct answers; Or one exhaustive answer. Even asking the right question is rather difficult.

Comment: @multiplexetliber Oh, my mistake, I don't know why I tend to write "[singular] women". I meant singular. For a second I thought you would refer to "muttern" as an archaic plural form, or whatever competed with "Mütter".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The singular form in genitive case of *»die Frau«* is *»der Frau«*. You can look this up in any conjugation table, for example, at [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Frau). So the correct expression is:

> auf der Frau Schoß

Compare:

> Das Buch lag auf ***des Mannes*** Schoß. (masculine)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***des Kindes*** Schoß. (neuter)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***der Frau*** Schoß. (feminine)

What is marked bold above is a left genitive attribute inside a dative object, which, in turn, is marked italics (which itself is inside a prepositional object, which is not marked, it is *»auf«* + the dative object). Of corse, you can use dative objects also without left genitive attributes, but then you have to use another determiner instead:

> Das Buch lag auf ***dem*** Schoß. (definite article)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***einem*** Schoß. (indefinite article)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***ihrem*** Schoß. (personal pronoun)

But you also can use right genitive attributes in nominal groups, but then you still need a definite article on the left side of the noun:

> Das Buch lag auf ***dem*** Schoß **des Mannes**. (definite article + right masculine attribute)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***dem*** Schoß **des Kindes**. (definite article + right neuter attribute)
>   Das Buch lag auf ***dem*** Schoß **der Frau**. (definite article + right feminine attribute)

---

> auf Mutters Schoß

This is more complicated, because this is not the normal behaviour of the word *»Mutter«*, which has no genitive-s. When you look at [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mutter), you will find:

> genitive of *die Mutter* is *der Mutter* (without *s* at the end)

So, here we have an exception. The standard form of *»die Mutter«* in genitive case is *»der Mutter«*, for example, when you use it as a genitive object or a right genitive attribute:

> Die Kinder standen traurig am Grab und gedachten **der Mutter.** (genitive object)
>   Die Kinder standen traurig am Grab **der Mutter.** (right genitive attribute inside a dative object inside a prepositional object)
>   <sup>*(note: am = an dem = preposition + article)*</sup>

But *»Mutter«* will get an extra *s* at the end when used as left genitive attribute, but only if used without an article:

> Die Kinder standen traurig an **Mutters** Grab. (left genitive attribute without article)
>   Die Kinder standen traurig an **der Mutter** Grab. (left genitive attribute with article)

This is true for all terms for female family relationships when used as left genitive attribute without its article:

> Ich fahre mit dem Auto **der Schwester.** (right attribute)
>   Ich fahre mit **der Schwester** Auto. (left attribute with article)
>   Ich fahre mit **Schwesters** Auto. (left attribute without article)

This works also with *Tante, Oma, Cousine, Nichte* and of course also with *Mutter.*

Masculine relatives always have an *s* at the end in genitive case:

> Ich fahre mit dem Auto **des Vaters.** (right attribute)
>   Ich fahre mit **des Vaters** Auto. (left attribute with article)
>   Ich fahre mit **Vaters** Auto. (left attribute without article)

So, the genitive *s* is always there when you use terms for masculine relatives, i.e., the *s* for left genitive attributes without article is not an exception.

---

**About usage:**

Left genitive attributes become more and more outdated. They are still correct, but the standard usage is the right genitive attribute:

> Ich nehme die Tabletten auf **meines Arztes** Empfehlung. (correct, but outdated)
>   Ich nehme die Tabletten auf Empfehlung **meines Arztes**. (modern standard)

---

**Other questions, not answered here:**

- **»Futtern wie bei Muttern«**
  You already linked to the right question in your posting, so you already know that this is something completely different (it is a regional dialect).
- **Fugenlaut**
  Also epentheses are something completely different. When you [search for "Fugenlaut"](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fugenlaut) you will find lots of questions dealing with this topic.

Comment: Searching "Muttern Sohn" does yield results, so I'm sure the linked comment doesn't tell the whole story (though it's appearing now as "Mutterns", surely a backformation, and for the nominative as well).

Comment: Saying "der Schwester Auto" without any remark to the oddity and uncommonness, is odd. In contrast, I find *Der Sonne letzter Strahl* slightly acceptable. The question is, basically, why is it *Sonnenstrahl*? Sonne is definitely singular--is it? I'm so happy I found that example right now, while. *Fugenlaut* and *Flottenmanagement* would be debatable; I'll have to brace myself for opinions about "epentheses" of "Sonn-Strahl"; Given sun's PIE root reconstructions, -n or no -n still seems to be a debatable question.

Comment: You can ask as many quastions as you want, but please split them up in separate Postings. Only one question is allowed per posting. Genitiv endings and epentheses are two different topics, therefor you have to ask in two separate postings.

Comment: *»Saying "der Schwester Auto" without any remark to the oddity and uncommonness, is odd«* Didn't you read the section »About usage«? There I clearly said *»Left genitive attributes become more and more outdated«*.

Comment: I might have missewd that remark in all the fluff. However, it doesn't say that it were odd, or declining for any other reason, and still leaves me wondering whether it was ever *usual*. This grammatical quirk, the homophony with the nominative, might be *the leading cause* for the move to using genitive *von* constructions *von der Frau* constructions. That's not off-topic. It's a broad, but self-contained and hence specific enough question, in my mind. The feigned level of incompetence in the title seems to have thrown you off.

Comment: Ironically, this construction isn't in decline. The whole problem is that there is no *declination*. I'm so sorry for this pun :D