# "Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar Strand." — Why not "dem"?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

Is this really correct?

> "Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar Strand."

Should it not be *dem*?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Do you think it's OK? If not, what are your concerns? How would you interpret the sentence grammar-wise?

Comment: I am just learning German. I came across:

Comment: This line is from the poem _Sehnsucht_ written by Elisabeth von Österreich
(Sisi).

Comment: I asked a similar question here https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50067/auf-dem-schoß-der-frau-auf-der-fraus-schoß The answer is of course unconvincing. A simpler answer would admit that females, like the isar, simply could not possess anything and therefore the female genitive case inflection is practically useless. j/k of course but you cannot deny the evidence

Comment: Such things are extremely rare, it is far more common that you've found some uncommon case. German grammar is very logic and trustable, although it is more complex and much harder to learn automatized as it looks on the first spot. If you are a programmer, it is like a low-level programming language.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to count it as a duplicate, but https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52752/der-widerspenstigen-z%c3%a4hmung seem at least related. Maybe the grammatical structure gets clearer it you reword the sentence as "Ich sehne mich nach dem Strand der Isar".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck It is not a duplicate, but it is very closely related.

Comment: potential doublet of https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50067/auf-dem-scho%c3%9f-der-frau-auf-der-fraus-scho%c3%9f

Answer (score 17):

### Short answer

> Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar Strand.

Here, *der Isar* is a so-called preposed genitive that prececdes the dative noun *Strand*.

### Long answer

#### Construction with dative

The phrase *sich nach etwas sehnen* demands the dative. Examples with all grammatical cases are:

> - Ich sehne mich nach *der Insel*. (feminine singular)
> - Ich sehne mich nach *dem Haus*. (neuter singular)
> - **Ich sehne mich nach *dem Strand*. (masculine singular)**
> - Ich sehne mich nach *den Inseln/Häusern/Stränden*. (plural)

Now, we want to refer to a particular beach: the Isar beach. In German one can use the compound noun *Isarstrand*, the gender of which is determined by the last composite, *Strand*:

> Ich sehne mich nach *dem Isarstrand*. (masculine singular)

#### Alternative construction with genitive

The content of the previous sentence can be expressed in another way using a genitive:

> Ich sehne mich nach *dem Strand der Isar*.

In this construction, the genitive *der Isar* is postposed, i. e., it succeeds *dem Strand*. In general, genitives may also occur *preposed*, especially when they involve a proper noun or when the construction is a fixed phrase. In this case, the article is omitted, which in the following examples I indicated by striking them through:

> - Evas <s>der</s> Freund
> - meines Vaters <s>das</s> Haus
> - meiner Mutter <s>das</s> Haus
> - meines Herzens <s>die</s> Qual
> - [Des Kaisers <s>die neuen</s> neue Kleider](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_Kaisers_neue_Kleider)
> - [Der Widerspenstigen <s>die</s> Zähmung](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Widerspenstigen_Z%C3%A4hmung)
>
> and also
>
> - der Isar <s>dem</s> Strand

The use of preposed genitives can still be found today, although they are perceived by many people as archaic:

> Des Weltmeisters Gedächtnis lässt bereits nach (Überschrift in der Neuen Zürcher Zeitung vom 23. Juli 2018, S. 35).
>
> <sup>(Source: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitiv#Attributiver_Genitiv))</sup>

Now, let's turn to the original sentence

> Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar Strand.

From what we have learned so far, *der Isar Strand* is a valid preposed-genitive construction, in which the preposed genitive *der Isar* precedes the dative noun *Strand*.

Comment: Kann man theoretisch schreiben: "Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar ihren Strand." Oder ist das ein Regionalismus?

Comment: "Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar _ihrem_ Strand." Hört sich fürchterlich an für mich; entweder die poetische Version "der Isar Strand" oder die "normale" Version "Ich sehne mich nach dem Strand der Isar".

Comment: Dativ + Possesivpronomen als Ersatz für den Genitiv kommt in manchen Dialekten und regionalen Varianten des Deutschen vor, in der Standardsprache ist das falsch.

Comment: Hier fehlt,, dass *nach etwas sehnen* regelmäßig Dativ erfordert, *nach dem Strand*, *nach der Isar*, dass demnach entweder *nach der Isar Strand* zurück im Nominativ lauten müsste *die Isar Strand* - was nicht der Standard ist (regional aber bspw. *die Isar ihr Strand*) - oder dass eine taugliche Unterscheidung fehlt - die sächlich oder männlich mit Morphem *-es, des Mannes Hand* beigebracht wird - zwischen Genitiv und Dativ weiblich, sowie Nominativ männlich, *der*, daher gänzlich andere Ausdrücke bevorzugt werden; Dass die Konstruktion *rein* literarisch Platz haben mag.

Comment: Erwähnenswert wäre eventuell auch, ob ein phonetischer Unterschied zwischen nominativ *der Isarstrand* und genitive *der Isar Strand*. Was hinfällig ist insoweit es kein weitläufig gesprochenes Konstrukt ist.

Comment: @vectory: "dass demnach entweder nach der Isar Strand zurück im Nominativ lauten müsste die Isar Strand" - kannst du das ausführen? Ich verstehe nicht, was du hier zu sagen versuchst. Da "der" gar nicht der Artikel für das Wort "Strand" ist, ändert er sich auch nicht, wenn sich der Kasus von "Strand" ändert. "regional aber bspw. *die Isar ihr Strand*" - ist das so? Ich kenne lediglich die regionale Ausdrucksweise "der Isar ihr Strand". "daher gänzlich andere Ausdrücke bevorzugt werden; Dass die Konstruktion *rein* literarisch Platz haben mag." - auch, wenn die Verwendung de Genitivs ...

Comment: ... zurückgeht, ist es wohl eher abwegig, zu behaupten, dass die Genetivform weiblicher Substantive heutzutage (Stand 2020) bereits komplett außer Mode gekommen und rein in "literarischem Kontext" zu finden ist. Auch die Konstruktion, den Genitiv voranzustellen, ist zwar im gesprochenen Deutsch in der Tat kaum mehr vorhanden, aber im Schriftdeutsch keineswegs so selten, dass sie einem (als Deutschlernendem) nicht geläufig sein sollte. Ansonsten wird man bereits Probleme damit haben, Märchentitel wie "Des Kaisers neue Kleider" (= Die neuen Kleider des Kaisers) zu verstehen.

Comment: @vectory - "der Isarstrand" is only stressed on the "I" of Isar, while "der Isar Strand" is also stressed on the "I" of Isar but more predominantly on Strand. So, yes, you hear a difference.

Comment: Das sollte wohl heißen, ein Fremdsprecher könnte auf die Idee kommen, dass es so heißen müsste (irrealis), da er den von mic eben angesprochenen Unterschied gegebenenfalls nicht kennt. Ich schrieb ausdrücklich entweder-oder. Habe beim erneuten Lesen aber auch erstmal gestutzt. (PS: mdas hatte ich so ähnlich gestern schonmal kommentiert, aber grob falsch und nun hoffentlich richtig)

Answer (score 3):

This is just a supplement to Björn Friedrich's neat answer.

If one omits "der Isar" as the genitive attribute belonging to "Strand", one gets "Ich seh'n mich nach Strand". One can of course criticize that a "dem" is missing ("Ich seh'n mich nach **dem** Strand"), but the meaning is nevertheless absolutely clear. In the case of abstracta the omission of the article is completely usual: "Ich seh'n mich nach Ruhe / Liebe / Aufmerksamkeit ... ". For the concretum "Strand" this is possibly unusual, but not at all incomprehensible.

Moreover one has to look at the context: As user9551 comments, the phrase is a line of a poem by empress Elisabeth of Austria. Here is a longer quotation:

> ...
> Aber war ich die Frühlingswonne
> hier in dem fernen, fremden Land?
> Ich seh'n mich nach der Heimat Sonne,
> Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar Strand.
> ...

It is obvious that empress Elisabeth chose a poetic formulation which forms a rhyme with "Land". And let's face it: It sounds much better than a grammatically faultless formulation, likewise "der Heimat Sonne". Besides, in the latter case "Ich seh'n mich nach Sonne" is absolutely correct even in the absence of an article.

An alternative would have been "Ich sehn' mich nach dem Isarstrand", but this sounds not as nice, especially following after the line "Ich seh'n mich nach der Heimat Sonne".

Let me finally mention that constructions of the form "noun with (attributive) prenominal genitive" are not that unusual as one may believe if one reads "der Isar Strand". However, frequently they have an antiquated touch, and constructions of the form "noun with (attributive) postnominal genitive" seem to be prevalent. I think the following  is a general rule:

> A noun requires an article if it occurs with a postnominal genitive. Example: *Er wartet auf das Urteil des Richters.*
> An article must not be used if a noun occurs with a prenominal genitive. Example: *Er wartet auf des Richters Urteil.*

In other words, a prenominal genitive "absorbs" the article. In fact, there is no adequate position for an article - it simply does not fit before and not after the prenominal genitive. In some dialects one uses ugly phrases like *Er wartet auf dem Richter sein Urteil* or *[Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwiebelfisch_(Kolumne))*. Here the possessive pronoun "sein" is a sort of substitute for the omitted article - but that cannot be a serious solution.

Here are some more examples for prenominal genitives.

- Des Kaisers neue Kleider.
- Viele Jäger sind des Hasen Tod.
- Jeder ist seines Glückes Schmied.
- Des Mannes liebstes Spielzeug ist sein Auto.
- Das also war des Pudels Kern.
- Des Trainers Ansehen ist gewachsen.
- Er sah Annas Vater. [This is the usual construction when used with names, altough also *Er sah den Vater Annas* or *Er sah den Vater von Anna* are in use.]

See also [here](https://www.ling.uni-potsdam.de/%7Ezimmermann/papers/MZ2002-Genitive.pdf) for a more rigid linguistic treatment.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your sentence starting with "In some dialects one uses ugly phrases". I have no objections to the statement you are making, but it seems to be coming out of the blue, as it appears to be unrelated to the preceding statement.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I wanted to say that "sein" is a sort of substitute for the omitted article belonging to "Richter" and "Tod". See mtwde's comment to Björn Friedrich's answer: *Kann man theoretisch schreiben: "Ich sehn' mich nach der Isar ihren Strand." Oder ist das ein Regionalismus?*