# Accusative in the sentence " (Sie) töteten der Sonne Glanz"

Tags: article, genitive, accusative, poetry

From the poem Nacht:

"Finstre, schwarze Riesenfalter
töteten der Sonne Glanz."

I understand "der Sonne" is the genitive case, but I cant spot the accusative case referring to "Glanz". Is it a poetic form omitting something? Is the sentence "Sie töteten den Glanz der Sonne" also correct?

Comment: Quite similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/52752/1696).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can change that to

> (Sie) töteten den Glanz der Sonne.

So "den Glanz" is the accusative object that is killed, and "der Sonne" is genitive referring to "Glanz".

It is a poetic form that would not be used in normal speech.